How to Add a New Command Line Parameter for Feature Toggle in QNX BSP Build?
I'm enhancing a QNX Board Support Package (BSP) project's build process to include a feature toggle via a new command line parameter, --new_feature=[enable|disable]. This parameter's purpose is to control the inclusion of a specific feature in the build, affecting compilation and the final build output based on its value.
What is the best practice for introducing a new command line parameter in a QNX BSP project that affects build logic?
